# Удалить всех пользователей postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Как корректно удалить всех пользователей СУБД, конечно, без `postgres`? На ум приходит только

```
delete * from pg_authid where rolname <> 'postgres'
```

но некорректно - не хватает что-то вроде `cascade`, т.к. в этом случае не выдаются ошибки, если есть связанные объекты (например, пользователь является владельцем базы).

Comment: Не стоит менять системные таблицы. Получите список пользователей и сгенерите требуемые drop user (или как там в постгрессе они удаляются)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do $$
    declare rname text;
    begin
      for rname in select rolname from pg_roles where rolname <> 'postgres'
        loop
          execute 'DROP ROLE ' || quote_ident(rname);
        end loop;
end $$;
```